# Calling a derived static method from a method in parent class in PHP

Tags: php, class, static, call

I've the following classes:

```
<?php
    Abstract Class A{
        public function foo(){
            self::bar();
        }

       Abstract public static function bar($arg);
    }

    Class B extends A{ 
        public static function bar(){
            echo "Class B";      
        }
    }

    Class C extends A{
        public static function bar(){
            echo "Class C";
        }
    }
?>
```

I need to that the method bar() for the instantiated class be called from foo():

```
<?php
  $obj1 = new B();
  $obj2 = new C();

  $obj1->foo(); // I expect to get 'Class B'
  $obj2->foo(); // I expect to get 'Class C'
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) for this

Basically in the abstract class you call `static::method()`. This uses the method of the class that made the call.

```
Abstract Class A{
    public function foo(){
        // Late static binding
        static::bar();
    }

   abstract public static function bar();
}
```

Comment: -1 - this example code does violate strict PHP standards and therefore spits notices.

Comment: Please see: http://3v4l.org/Ytl4m